# `TypeError: invalid type promotion` when appending to a heterogeneous numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have created an array with:

```
Ticket_data = np.empty((0,7),
                       dtype='str,datetime64[m],datetime64[m],str,str,str,str')
```

and I am trying to append data with:

```
lineitem = [str(data[0][0]), OpenDT, CloseDT, str(data[0][11]),
            str(data[0][12]), str(data[0][13]), str(data[0][14])]
```

Where `OpenDT` and `CloseDT` were created with `np.datetime64(DTstring, 'm')`

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Daily Report.py", line 25, in <module>
    np.append(Ticket_data, np.array([lineitem]), axis=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3884, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

---

Edit:

```
print np.array([lineitem])
```

outputs

```
[['21539' '2015-06-30T10:46-0700' '2015-06-30T10:55-0700' 'Testtext'
 'Testtext2' 'Testtext3' 'Testtext5']]
```

and

```
print np.array([lineitem], dtype=Ticket_data.dtype)
```

Outputs

```
[[('', 245672259890L, datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), '', '', '', '')
  ('', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30, 17, 46), datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), '', '', '', '')
  ('', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30, 17, 55), datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), '', '', '', '')
  ('', 7741528753124368710L, datetime.datetime(1982, 11, 21, 6, 33), '', '', '', '')
  ('', 7959953343691844691L, datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), '', '', '', '')
  ('', datetime.datetime(5205, 7, 21, 7, 42), datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), '', '', '', '')
  ('', 2336635297857499728L, 2338042681633169744L, '', '', '', '')]]
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Regarding your edit, you should omit the extra brackets around `[lineitem]` (i.e. `np.array(lineitem, dtype=Ticket_data.dtype)`)

Comment: It then gives me a dimensional error when I try ```Ticket_data = np.append(Ticket_data, np.array(lineitem, dtype=Ticket_data.dtype), axis=0)```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, *fields* in a structured array are not the same thing as *dimensions* in a regular ndarray. You want your `Ticket_label` array to be *1-dimensional*, but for each row element in that dimension to contain *7 fields*, e.g.:

```
Ticket_data = np.empty((0,),
                       dtype='str,datetime64[m],datetime64[m],str,str,str,str')
```

Now in order to concatenate `lineitem` to `Ticket_data`, it must first be implicitly cast from nested lists to an array. Since you don't specify separate `dtype`s for each field, numpy treats `lineitem` as a homogeneous array, and finds a common `dtype` that each element can be safely promoted to.

For example:

```
lineitem = ['foo', np.datetime64('1979-03-22T19:00', 'm'),
            np.datetime64('1979-03-22T19:00', 'm'), 'bar', 'baz', 'a', 'b']

np.array(lineitem)
# array(['21539', '2015-06-30T10:46-0700', '2015-06-30T10:55-0700',
#        'Testtext', 'Testtext2', 'Testtext3', 'Testtext5'], 
#       dtype='|S21')
```

In this example, every element is cast to a 21-long string. The `dtype` of this array does not match that of `Ticket_data`, and since there is no safe way to cast `'|S21'` to `'np.datetime64[m]'` you get an `invalid type promotion` error.

You could avoid the error by explicitly casting `lineitem` to an array, specifying the correct dtypes for each field:

```
np.array([tuple(lineitem)], dtype=Ticket_data.dtype)
```

Note that I'm casting `lineitem` to a tuple - this is necessary in order for the elements in `lineitem` to be interpreted as separate *fields* rather than separate *elements*. The result is an array of shape `(1,)` (not `(1, 7)`):

```
np.array([tuple(lineitem)], dtype=Ticket_data.dtype).shape
# (1,)
```

If I *don't* cast `lineitem` to a tuple then I get a `(1, 7)` array, where each *individual* element in `lineitem` is interpreted as a *sequence* of `'str,datetime64[m],datetime64[m],str,str,str,str'`, resulting in the nonsense you showed in your edit.

The result can then be concatenated to `Ticket_label`.

---

As an aside, I strongly recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) instead of structured arrays for dealing with heterogeneous data such as this.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I later convert it to pandas later for formatting so I might just start as that.