# Concatenating numpy.void with numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

(Warning - I am a newbie)

I imported mat files using scipy.io:

```
   data = spio.loadmat('data.mat', struct_as_record=True, squeeze_me=True)
   data = data['b']
   >>> <type 'numpy.void'>
```

Which gave me a file that is of type numpy.void. Each line has 17 entries that are types string, float, array

```
print(data.shape)
>>> (11000,)
```

I have another list of strings which I converted to a numpy.array:

```
filenames = np.array([filenames])
filenames = np.ndarray.flatten(filenames)
print (filenames.shape)
>>> (11000,)

print(data.dtype)
print(filenames.dtype)

>>> [('fieldname1', 'O'), ('fieldname2', 'O'), ('fieldname3', 'O'), ('fieldname4', 'O'), ('fieldname5', 'O'), ('fieldname6', 'O'), ('fieldname7', 'O'), ('fieldname8', 'O'), ('fieldname9', 'O'), ('fieldname10', 'O'), ('fieldname11', 'O'), ('fieldname12', 'O'), ('fieldname13', 'O'), ('fieldname14', 'O'), ('fieldname15', 'O'), ('fieldname16', 'O'), ('fieldname17', 'O')]
>>> |S16
```

I want to concatenate these along a column:

```
NEW = np.concatenate((data, filenames), axis=1)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
>>> TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172991/typeerror-invalid-type-promotion-when-appending-to-a-heterogeneous-numpy-arra but I still get the same error.

Comment: `data.dtype` is more useful to us than `type`.  `concatenate` does not work to add a field to a structured array.  You need something lime `recfunctions.append_field` (I'll lookup details later).

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj I have updated my question.

Comment: `append_fields`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5288736

Comment: The 'O' dtypes mean the fields are objects.  Check the contents.  Sometimes loads from matlab can be complex.  It has to translate foreign things like cells and structs.

Comment: Thank you @hpauj! that worked. Want to move it to an answer? So that I can accept. It didn't seem to give any trouble with the objects, I think because they are not nested further than one level. I did find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008608/scipy-io-loadmat-nested-structures-i-e-dictionaries for just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recfunctions` is a module with tools for fiddling with structured arrays (and their variant, `recarray`).  It requires separate import.  In my experience it is also somewhat buggy.

```
In [158]: from numpy.lib import recfunctions
```

Make an array with several object dtype fields:

```
In [159]: dat = np.empty((3,),dtype=('O,O,O'))
In [160]: dat
Out[160]: 
array([(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O'), ('f2', 'O')])
```

After a bit of trial-n-error in calling `append_field`, this works:

```
In [161]: names = np.array(['one','two','three'])
In [162]: dat1 = recfunctions.append_fields(dat, 'names', names, usemask=False)
In [163]: dat1
Out[163]: 
array([(None, None, None, 'one'), (None, None, None, 'two'),
       (None, None, None, 'three')],
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O'), ('f2', 'O'), ('names', '<U5')])
```

But check the contents of the data that's loaded from MATLAB.  The .mat may contain structs and cells, which `loadmat` has to translate into `numpy` equivalents.  To do so it makes extensive use of object dtype arrays.