# Subtract two columns using conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, if-statement

[image]I have two date columns, I want to subtract the two columns based on conditions. First check for all the blanks in the first column and then check second column for blanks and the third condition check if the subtracted dates are less than one. If these conditions are satisfied, carry out subtraction of the the two columns. Something like this:

'''if [Recommendation signed] = null or [Executed Date] = null or Duration.Days([Contract Executed Date]-[Recommendation signed]) < 1 then null else Duration.Days([Contract Executed Date]-[Recommendation signed])'''

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using apply function. For example you want to store the value into a new column called `day difference`.

Make sure these were datetime columns (if they're not apply `to_datetime` function).

```
df['Recommendation signed'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Recommendation signed']).dt.date
df['Executed Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Executed Date']).dt.date
df['Contract Executed Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Contract Executed Date']).dt.date

def substract_columns(row):
  if pd.isnull(row['Recommendation signed']) or pd.isnull(row['Executed Date']) or ((row['Contract Executed Date'] - row['Recommendation signed']) == '0 days'):
    return None
  else:
    row['Contract Executed Date'] - row['Recommendation signed']

df['day difference'] = df.apply(substract_columns, axis=1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I tried and I am getting TypeError: 'ExcelFile' object does not support item assignment. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I tried and the code worked. Unfortunately I am getting all the values as none. When the difference should be 122 rows.

Comment: can you edit your question and add your sample data so we can take a look

Comment: I have updated the column and its values. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.  Since no data was provided I created my own generator.  The solution is contained within `find_duration` and how it is used in `df.apply(find_duration, axis=1)`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import islice

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

RECOMMENDATION_IS_PENDING = "RECOMMENDATION_IS_PENDING"
EXECUTION_IS_PENDING = "EXECUTION_IS_PENDING"
COMPLETED_IN_LESS_THAN_ONE_DAY = "COMPLETED_IN_LESS_THAN_ONE_DAY"
COMPLETED_IN_MORE_THAN_ONE_DAY = "COMPLETED_IN_MORE_THAN_ONE_DAY"

MIN_YEAR = 1900
MAX_YEAR = 2020
NUM_YEARS = MAX_YEAR - MIN_YEAR + 1
START_DATE = datetime(MIN_YEAR, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
END_DATE = START_DATE + timedelta(days=365 * NUM_YEARS)

NUM_RECORDS = 20


def random_datetime(rng, dt):
    return START_DATE + (END_DATE - START_DATE) * rng.uniform()


def less_than_one_day(rng, dt):
    hours = int(np.round(23.0 * rng.uniform()))
    return dt + timedelta(hours=hours)


def more_than_one_day(rng, dt):
    days = 1 + int(np.round(100.0 * rng.uniform()))
    return dt + timedelta(days=days)


def null_datetime(rng, dt):
    return None

class RecordGenerator:
    PROBABILITIES = {
        RECOMMENDATION_IS_PENDING: 0.1,
        EXECUTION_IS_PENDING: 0.2,
        COMPLETED_IN_LESS_THAN_ONE_DAY: 0.2,
        COMPLETED_IN_MORE_THAN_ONE_DAY: 0.5,
    }

    GENERATORS = {
        RECOMMENDATION_IS_PENDING: (null_datetime, random_datetime),
        EXECUTION_IS_PENDING: (random_datetime, null_datetime),
        COMPLETED_IN_LESS_THAN_ONE_DAY: (random_datetime, less_than_one_day),
        COMPLETED_IN_MORE_THAN_ONE_DAY: (random_datetime, more_than_one_day),
    }

    def __init__(self, seed=0):
        self.rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            res = self.rng.uniform()
            for kind, val in self.PROBABILITIES.items():
                res -= val
                if res <= 0.0:
                    break
            recommendation_signed_fn, execution_date_fn = self.GENERATORS[kind]
            recommendation_signed = recommendation_signed_fn(self.rng, None)
            execution_date = execution_date_fn(self.rng, recommendation_signed)
            yield recommendation_signed, execution_date


def find_duration(df):
    duration = df["execution_date"] - df["recommendation_signed"]
    if duration is pd.NaT or duration < pd.Timedelta(days=1):
        return None
    return duration


if __name__ == "__main__":
    records = RecordGenerator()
    recommendation_signed_dates, execution_dates = zip(*islice(records, NUM_RECORDS))
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        "recommendation_signed": recommendation_signed_dates,
        "execution_date": execution_dates,
    })
    print(f"`recommendation_signed` is null: [{df['recommendation_signed'].isnull().sum()}]")
    print(f"`execution_date` is null: [{df['execution_date'].isnull().sum()}]")
    print(f"`completed_in_less_than_one_day`: [{((df['execution_date'] - df['recommendation_signed']) < pd.Timedelta(days=1)).sum()}]")
    print(f"`completed_in_more_than_one_day`: [{((df['execution_date'] - df['recommendation_signed']) >= pd.Timedelta(days=1)).sum()}]")
    df["completion_time"] = df.apply(find_duration, axis=1)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
`recommendation_signed` is null: [2]
`execution_date` is null: [2]
`completed_in_less_than_one_day`: [4]
`completed_in_more_than_one_day`: [12]
        recommendation_signed             execution_date completion_time
0  1986-06-25 08:07:14.808395 1986-08-25 08:07:14.808395         61 days
1  1951-03-25 17:08:27.986156 1951-05-30 17:08:27.986156         66 days
2  2007-11-01 03:42:35.672304 2007-11-02 01:42:35.672304             NaT
3  1995-09-26 12:52:16.917964 1995-09-27 00:52:16.917964             NaT
4  2011-12-03 23:24:45.808880 2011-12-11 23:24:45.808880          8 days
5                         NaT 1902-06-12 22:41:33.183052             NaT
6  1994-02-04 07:01:47.052493 1994-05-03 07:01:47.052493         88 days
7  1996-08-19 20:06:42.217770 1996-10-05 20:06:42.217770         47 days
8  1914-04-21 14:09:37.598524 1914-06-25 14:09:37.598524         65 days
9  2014-03-25 07:15:55.137157                        NaT             NaT
10 1950-02-21 13:04:11.684479 1950-03-20 13:04:11.684479         27 days
11 1955-02-27 21:06:22.090510 1955-04-26 21:06:22.090510         58 days
12                        NaT 1974-09-07 20:55:17.329968             NaT
13 1974-08-07 21:21:33.578522 1974-11-10 21:21:33.578522         95 days
14 1943-06-22 15:59:39.451885 1943-08-06 15:59:39.451885         45 days
15 1907-04-14 20:35:27.269379 1907-06-21 20:35:27.269379         68 days
16 1925-06-10 13:05:57.968982 1925-06-24 13:05:57.968982         14 days
17 1943-12-25 06:52:07.566032 1943-12-25 19:52:07.566032             NaT
18 2019-07-07 12:44:00.201327 2019-07-07 14:44:00.201327             NaT
19 1919-07-05 05:38:11.678570                        NaT             NaT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df['Recommendation Signed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Recommendation Signed'], errors='coerce')
df['Contract Executed Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Contract Executed Date'], errors='coerce')
df['date_difference'] = np.where(df['Recommendation Signed'].isnull() | df['Contract Executed Date'].isnull() | ((df['Contract Executed Date'] - df['Recommendation Signed'] ) < timedelta(days=1)), np.datetime64('NaT'), df['Contract Executed Date'] - df['Recommendation Signed'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I applied your code and I am getting the following error. **TypeError: invalid type promotion.** I checked and it seems that the issue is with regards to array. I have attached the link as it went way above my head of what is exactly is going on in background. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172991/typeerror-invalid-type-promotion-when-appending-to-a-heterogeneous-numpy-arra

Comment: I have edited the answer. Can you check if it is working ?